# apache active mq the message is dequed but method with @JmsListener is not called

Tags: jms, spring-jms

I am facing one problem where the message in Acpache ActiveMQ is dequeued in the console but the consumer method is not called which has @JmsListener, though the number of consumers shows 7.

**Configuration code:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfiguration {
    private static final String DEFAULT_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";
    private static final long DEFAULT_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT = 1000L;
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY = "25";

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL(DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerFactory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        listenerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        listenerFactory.setReceiveTimeout(DEFAULT_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);
        listenerFactory.setConcurrency(DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY);
        return listenerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
        template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        return template;
    }
}
```

**Listener Code:**

```
@JmsListener(destination = Constants.EXPORT_QUEUE)
    public void onExportMessageReceive(Message message) {
        if (message instanceof Message) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made one change of using spring-jms of version 4.3.22-RELEASE.

Now it works like below:
Initially the 3 no of consumers and max 25 are defined in the application. And now if more messages are produced lets say 25 then the consumers will remain 3 only and the count of consumers will increase gradually based on the pending messages. It may go upto 13 but will not create max consumers to 25 as per definition.
Due to this the order might change. for ex:
Message1   Consumer1   (in-progress)
Message2   Consumer2   (in-progress)
Message3   Consumer3   (in-progress)

Now if these messages are under process and new messages have come up then they will wait for the consumers as per below
Message4   Consumer1   (waiting)
Message5   Consumer2   (waiting)
Message6   Consumer3   (waiting)

Now since these messages 4-6 are in pending state and new messages keep coming up which enforces system to create new consumers then those message will be consumed first.
Message7   Consumer4   (in-progress)
Message8   Consumer5   (in-progress)

Message7-8 are consumed first then Message4-6. But they will be consumed once the consumers got free.